# Why does Eclipse warn me to add a serialVersionUID?

Tags: java, eclipse, graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why should I bother about serialVersionUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/why-should-i-bother-about-serialversionuid)

I've been learning how to use Java's graphics classes. When I made a simple FlowLayout, I got a warning in Eclipse IDE telling me I should add a serialversionUID before my Layout contructor class.

It now looks like:

```
public class ShowFlowLayout extends JFrame{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public ShowFlowLayout() {...
```

What is a serialVersionUID? Is it important to have?

Comment: That's part of the contract for classes that implement Serializable, of which JFrame is one. But it's a warning, not an error, so feel free to ignore it if you wish or to use a trivial serial version id or an annotation to have the compiler ignore it,...

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse asks you to add `serialVersionUID` to all serializable classes. Since JFrame implements `Serializable`, your class does too, hence it *should* have a `serialVersionUID`. Note that it is not *required*, only [strongly suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/why-should-i-bother-about-serialversionuid).